# Adding to a table using MVC 5, and reset Id after deleting records

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

I have 2 questions:

First I wrote a code to add doctors to database, at the beginning the code worked fine but after  adding validation the doctor information does not added to table.. when I press add button the URL goes to: **/Doctors/Save**
Why the data does not saved in database? And why after I pressed Add button the program does not redirect me to Add view?

In controller there `Add()` action is for the Add view which contains the adding form.. `Save()` action is for the `Html.BeginForm("Save","Doctors")` that is inside the `Add` view..

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Add()
    {  return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Save(Doctor doctor)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new DoctorViewModel
            {
                Doctor = doctor

            };
            return View("Add", viewModel);
        }

      if(doctor.Id == 0) {
      _context.Doctors.Add(doctor);
      _context.SaveChanges();
      return Redirect("Add");
        }
      else
      {
          var doctorInDb = _context.Doctors.Single(c => c.Id == doctor.Id);
          doctorInDb.Name = doctor.Name;
          doctorInDb.Symbol = doctor.Symbol;
          doctorInDb.Office = doctor.Office;
          doctorInDb.Phone = doctor.Phone;
          doctorInDb.Email = doctor.Email;
          _context.SaveChanges();
          return Redirect("Add");
        }

       }
```

Add view:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.DoctorViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Adding a Doctor</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Doctors"))
{
    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Doctor.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Doctor.Name , new { @class = "form-control"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Doctor.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Doctor.Symbol)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Doctor.Symbol, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Doctor.Symbol)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Doctor.Phone)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Doctor.Phone, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Doctor.Phone)
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Doctor.Office)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Doctor.Office, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Doctor.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Doctor.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Doctor.Id)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <h5> Add </h5> </button>     @Html.ActionLink("Go to doctors list", "DoctorList")
}

    @section scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

        }
```

Second question:

Can I reset the Id, after deleting all records from table, from the controller?

Here is my reset code:

```
public ActionResult Reset()
    {
        _context.PSRs.RemoveRange(_context.PSRs);

        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("PSR");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the Id'?

Comment: When I delete table records, the Id starts from the last record.. I want to make it start from 1 after deleting all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for what you have said I believe that:

> First I wrote a code to add doctors to database, at the beginning the
>   code worked fine but after adding validation the doctor information
>   does not added to table.. **when I press add button the URL goes to:
>   /Doctors/Save Why the data does not saved in database?**

It looks like the reason the data is not saved in database is because your Model is invalid:

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = new DoctorViewModel
        {
            Doctor = doctor

        };
        return View("Add", viewModel);
    }
```

So you can debug your code to see the reason why it is invalid. If you want, you can insert this code:

```
var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values
    .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
    .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
```

before `var viewModel` and a breakpoint on it so you don´t need to navigate in the properties during debug.

> **And why after I
>   pressed Add button the program does not redirect me to Add view?**
>
> In controller there Add() action is for the Add view which contains
>   the adding form.. Save() action is for the
>   Html.BeginForm("Save","Doctors") that is inside the Add view..

You are not being redirect to the "Add view" because you are not saving doctor successfully (ModelState is invalid) therefore it just renders Add view (URL keeps as /Doctors/Save) but not redirect to it.

> Second question:
>
> Can I reset the Id, after deleting all records from table, from the
>   controller?

Don´t know the answer for this one, maybe you should have splitted the question in two, so people can answer to one question but not to the other one.

Regards,

Comment: Thank you a lot.. the message shows that: "The Id field is required"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know either for the second question.
but for the first one:
Are you certain that Doctor Id is set as AutoGenerated Key?
Perhaps you can show the doctor class

Comment: Yes it is AutoGenerated Key